# how to find out number of leap years if you have entered date and some x seconds to add

Tags: c, date, seconds, leap-year

So let me explain:
On input u got:
e.g.:
5 7 1904 5 5 5
675876789
day,month,year hours,mins,secs and some number k.
At the output you need to get:
4.12.1925. 20:38:14

I'm constantly getting 5.12.1925 20:38:14 just because of leap years and my algorithm breaks there. I'm posting my code bellow if anyone knows how to help me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int D, M, G, H, m, s;
    unsigned int k;
    unsigned int ks,km,kH,kG,kM,kD;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&D,&M,&G,&H,&m,&s);
    while(G<1900 || G>2015)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",&D,&M,&G,&H,&m,&s);
    }
    int month;
    scanf("%u",&k);
    if(M == 1)
    {
        month=31;
    }
    if(M == 2 && G%4==0 && G%100!=0 && G%400==0)
    {
        month=29;
    }
    if(M == 2 && G%4!=0 && G%100!=0 && G%400!=0)
    {
        month=28;
    }
    if(M == 3)
    {
        month=31;
    }
    if(M == 4)
    {
        month=30;
    }
    if(M == 5)
    {
        month=31;
    }
    if(M == 6)
    {
        month=30;
    }
    if(M == 7)
    {
        month=31;
    }
    if(M == 8)
    {
        month=31;
    }
    if(M == 9)
    {
        month=30;
    }
    if(M == 10)
    {
        month=31;
    }
    if(M == 11)
    {
        month=30;
    }
    if(M == 12)
    {
        month=31;
    }
    kG=k/31536000;
    G=G+kG;
    k=k-kG*31536000;
    kM=k/(86400*month);
    k=k-kM*86400*month;
    kD=k/86400;
    k=k-kD*86400;
    kH=k/3600;
    k=k-kH*3600;
    km=k/60;
    ks=k-km*60;
    s=s+ks;
    m=m+km;
    H=H+kH;
    M=M+kM;
    while(s>=60)
    {
        m++;
        s-=60;
    }
    while(m>=60)
    {
        H++;
        m-=60;
    }
    while(H>=24)
    {
        D++;
        H-=24;
    }
    while(D>month)
    {
        M++;
        D-=31;
    }
    while(M>12)
    {
        G++;
        M-=12;
    }
    printf("%d.%d.%4d. %02d:%02d:%02d",D,M,G,H,m,s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "how to find out number of leap years" is unclear.  How many leap year since when?  Since 2000, since 1970, since 1AD?  Or do you want to know if a given year is a leap year?

Answer (score 2):

You should really use a decent library to do this. There are not only leap years; there is daylight savings time, and if you are asking about dates in the early last century, there will be a few calendar changes here and there, which you have no chance taking into account.

And at the very least you need to know the locale of the date, because daylight savings time is different from locale to locale.

That said, your logic for calculating which months are leap years is totally wrong. You need to learn the difference between && and ||. Try G = 2016 and M = 2: months (which is a misleading variable name for days in the month) will not be set at all.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like here, you have 31 days in every month:

```
while(D>month)
{
    M++;
    D-=31;
}
```

And, unrelated to this problem, you should also check the rules for leap years and the year 2000 (which is an exception to an exception).

Comment: Can You be more specific about rules of leap years. Should i make for-loop from starting year to ending year and count how many leap years there is and then make a mid-value of those years or?

Answer (score -1):

Condition for leap year

if the year is divisible by 100 it must be divisible by 400 to be leap year;
and if the year is not divisible by 100 it would be leap year only if the year is divisible by 4;

i.e,

if (((year%100==0) && (year%400==0)) || ((year%100!=0) && (year%4==0))

code to find leap years in a range:

```
int leapyears(int start_year, int ending_year)
{
int k=0;
while (start_year<=ending year)
{
//&& operator have higher preference than ||
if (start_year%4==0 && start_year%100!=0 || start_year%400==0)
k++;
start_year++;
}
return k;
}
```

Comment: Basic maths: If the year is divisible by 100 then it will _always_ be divisible by 4. It's the century that must be divisible by 4, so the year must be divisible by 400. That's why 2000 was a leap year, and 1900 wasn't, and 2100 won't be.